# Como setar cor de fundo em múltiplas linhas de uma JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Gostaria de saber como setar a cor do background de múltiplas linhas da tabela. No código abaixo ele simplesmente seta o background em apenas uma linha, ou seja, no ultimo elemento do vetor. A ideia é passar uma lista de strings, e o código deve setar um fundo vermelho em todas as linhas da tabela que contenham as mesmas strings da lista passada.

```
public class ColorCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


private Color color = Color.RED;
private String textToColor;
private List<String> list;

public ColorCellRenderer(){  
    super();  
  }  

public ColorCellRenderer(String string) {
    textToColor = string;

}

public ColorCellRenderer(List<String> list2) {
    list = list2;
}



@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,   
        Object value,  
        boolean isSelected,   
        boolean hasFocus,   
        int row,   
        int column ) {  
    final java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    for (int c=0; c<list.size(); c++)
    {       

    Object val = table.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String sval = val.toString();
    System.out.println("##"+sval);      

    if (sval.equals(list.get(c))) {
     cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
       cellComponent.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    else {
     cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);        
     cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
    }
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}
```

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: [Como colorir linhas específicas de uma JTable?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4591/3117)

Comment: Neste caso do exemplo que você me passou @Math está ocorrendo o mesmo comportamento do meu código. Mas, muito obrigado.

Comment: Não cheguei a testar seu código, mas aquela resposta funcionou corretamente para mim. Você está dizendo que mesmo usando o código daquela resposta apenas linha do último elemento do vetor está sendo pintada?

Comment: Sim. De acordo com o código do exemplo, ele irá pintar em vermelho todas as linhas que tiverem o registro "vermelho", e é ai onde está o problema. Digamos que eu tenha numa coluna as linhas  {carro, casa, moto, avião} e eu desejo trocar o background para vermelho em todas as linhas, exceto "moto". O código não irá funcionar. No meu código esta acontecendo  a mesma coisa do exemplo, entretanto estou tentando percorrer uma list dos registros da table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo meu problema. Troquei o laço de repetição por esta condição.

```
if (list.contains(val.toString())) {
 cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
   cellComponent.setBackground(Color.red);
}
else {
 cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);        
 cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
    }
```

Comment: Se isso resolve seu problema você pode marcar sua resposta como aceita.