# Classificando com células coloridas e com coluna de Date

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho dois problemas para finalizar a minha tabela:

1) Tenho um `TableCellRenderer` customizado para pintar uma linha inteira baseada no valor de uma coluna. Funciona, porém quando clico para classificar, as cores das linhas não seguem a classificação. Ficam "doidas".

2) Preciso, na mesma tabela, classificar uma coluna por data, porém, apesar de muita pesquisa na internet, não entendi as soluções mostradas. Minha coluna está como `Object`, não `String`, nem `Integer`.

Aqui está meu *custom model*:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel() {
    Class[] types = new Class[]{java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class};

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types[columnIndex];
    }
};

model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"", "LINHA", "TRÂNSITO", "PROMOTOR", "<html>ORDEM NALINHA", "<html>ESTADO ORDEM NA LINHA", "TÉCNICO NA LINHA", "<html>ORDEM DESCONEXÃO", "ORDEM TIPO", "<html>DATA ORDEM EXECUÇÃO", "<html>ÚLTIMA CONEXÃO", "ESTADO"});
```

E aqui o custom TableCellRenderer:

```
table = new JTable(model) {
    private final Border outside = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, new Color(200, 200, 200));
    private final Border inside = new EmptyBorder(0, 1, 0, 1);
    private final Border highlight = new CompoundBorder(outside, inside);

    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;
        Object transito = getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
        Object linha = getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);

        /////////Start of conditions.
        if (linha.toString().length() != 12) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (transito.equals("Volto da Rua")) {
            comp.setBackground(new Color(255, 230, 150));
        }

        ...

        else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        /////////End of conditions.


        // Add a border to the selected row
        if (isRowSelected(row)) {
            jc.setBorder(highlight);
            comp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            comp.setFont(new Font("Open Sans", 1, 12));
        }

        return comp;
    }
};
```

A 9º coluna é a da data (DATA ORDEM EXECUÇÃO). Quando clico para classificar, fica como `String`:

> 31/03/2015
>  31/01/2015
>  30/03/2015
>  30/01/2015
>   29/03/2015
>  29/02/2015
>  29/01/2015

Ao invés de:

> 31/03/3015
>  30/03/2015
>  29/03/2015

(obs.: O formato da data é `dd/MM/yyyy`).

Então, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Sou novo em Java, portanto, se tiverem uma solução, poderia adaptar no código? Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: Printscreen das telas pra gente entender melhor

Comment: Não cheguei a entender sua dúvida por completo, mas talvez essa pergunta possa lhe ajudar: [Como colorir linhas específicas de uma JTable?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4591/3117)

Comment: @GeorgeCosta, o problema não estaria nos tipos definidos pra cada coluna? Sua coluna de data está como tipo String, enquanto deveria estar como tipo Date. Em outras palavras, o algoritmo de ordenação utilizado levará em consideração comparação com String e nao Data.

Comment: Como @cantoni disse, você definiu no model na primeira linha que a 9ª coluna é uma String, logo ele vai ordenar como String. A 10ª que é Object .