# Marcar/Desmarcar uma linha no JTable, mudando sua cor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Bom dia pessoal!

Sou novo aqui no fórum, peço desculpas se abri este tópico no local errado. Bom estou com um baita problema com uma ação que estou querendo fazer no Java Swing com o componente JTable, já procurei em vários lugares e nada que me de uma luz!

O que eu gostaria que funcionasse é o seguinte, eu tenho um JTable com vários resultados e quando o usuário clicar sobre uma linha está linha deve mudar de cor indicando que está selecionada (neste momento eu preencho um objeto com um valor, e a partir dai, nenhuma outra linha pode ser selecionada enquanto esta linha selecionada não for "desselecionada"), e quando for clicada novamente e desselecionada, ela volta a cor padrão. (O objeto que trava as demais linhas, volta a ser nulo neste momento, permitindo a outra linha ser selecionada).

Bom o código que consegui fazer até então foi este:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
int l = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
int c = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(table.getSelectedColumn());

                System.out.println("ROW: " + l + " | COLUMN: " + c);

                Component com = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(l, c), l, c);

                System.out.println("COMP: " + ((com.getBackground() == Color.RED) ? "É VERMELHO" : "NÃO É"));

                if (((com.getBackground() == Color.RED) && (services.getMarkFocus() != null))) {
                    System.out.println("PRETO");
                    com.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    services.setMarkFocus(null);
                } else if (((com.getBackground() != Color.RED) && (services.getMarkFocus() == null))) {
                    System.out.println("VERMELHO");
                    com.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    PlaceMark p = new PlaceMark();
                    p.setId(1);
                    services.setMarkFocus(p);
                }

                System.out.println("STATUS MARK: " + ((services.getMarkFocus() != null) ? true : false) + 
                        "\nVERMELHO? " + ((com.getBackground() == Color.RED) ? true : false));
                table.clearSelection();
            super.mouseClicked(e);
        }
```

Este código chega até a mudar a cor da linha, mas na segunda vez que ele puxa a linha "parece" que ele pega a cor da linha e diz que não é vermelha, sendo que no primeiro click ela se tornou vermelha.

OBS: Estou usando um AbstractTableModel, que eu fiz umas edições para colocar imagem na tabela.

Desde já fico no aguardo, e espero que alguém possa me dar uma luz.

Abração a todos...

SuperMock

Comment: Bem vindo só um esclarecimento, o SO não exatamente um **fórum** e sim **um site de perguntas e respostas**, portanto não se preocupe em postar no "local específico". http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Relacionado: [Como colorir linhas específicas de uma JTable?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4591/3117)

Comment: Esta pergunta de como colorir linhas específicas de uma JTable, faz esta mudança quando a JTable está sendo construída correto? Porque o que eu gostaria que acontecesse é que está mudança fosse em tempo de execução.

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas achei que pudesse ser relevante. Não tive tempo de tentar ver o seu caso em específico.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Quando a linha está selecionada (está em foco), por padrão o Java Swing altera a cor para azul.
Uma opção para você seria limpar a seleção da tabela antes de obter o componente.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int l = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
    int c = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(table.getSelectedColumn());

    //limpe a seleção antes de obter o component
    table.clearSelection();

    System.out.println("ROW: " + l + " | COLUMN: " + c);

    Component com = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(l, c), l, c);

    System.out.println("COMP: " + ((com.getBackground() == Color.RED) ? "É VERMELHO" : "NÃO É"));

    if (((com.getBackground() == Color.RED) && (services.getMarkFocus() != null))) {
        System.out.println("PRETO");
        com.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        services.setMarkFocus(null);
    } else if (((com.getBackground() != Color.RED) && (services.getMarkFocus() == null))) {
        System.out.println("VERMELHO");
        com.setBackground(Color.RED);
        PlaceMark p = new PlaceMark();
        p.setId(1);
        services.setMarkFocus(p);
    }

    System.out.println("STATUS MARK: " + ((services.getMarkFocus() != null) ? true : false)
            + "\nVERMELHO? " + ((com.getBackground() == Color.RED) ? true : false));

    super.mouseClicked(e);
}
```